# File names with space, sending quoted commands to shell?

Tags: file, rename, filenames, spaces, names

So I have a few files with spaces in them, I first remove spaces and put the "new names" in a list, then I construct a command to take old file name, which I put in quotes, and then the new file-name and rename them using mv and subprocess.run - but python is spitting out errors:

Here's the code:

```
import os
import subprocess

file_path = "/home/emil/import/"

files = os.listdir(file_path)

new_files = []


#Create new names

for each in files:
        print ("Taking file: ", each)
        new_name = each.replace(" ", "")
        final_name = file_path + new_name
        new_files.append(final_name)
        cmd = "mv \"" + file_path + each + "\" " + final_name
        print (cmd)
        subprocess.run([cmd])
```

And here is the output:

```
emil@TITAN:~/programmering$ ./call.py
Taking file:  test file1.pdf
mv "/home/emil/import/test file1.pdf" /home/emil/import/testfile1.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./call.py", line 22, in <module>
    subprocess.run([cmd])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mv "/home/emil/import/test file1.pdf" /home/emil/import/testfile1.pdf': 'mv "/home/emil/import/test file1.pdf" /home/emil/import/testfile1.pdf'
```

As you can see I print the variable cmd which I am sending to subprocess, and if I run that command individually it works great:

```
emil@TITAN:~/programmering$ mv "/home/emil/import/test file1.pdf" /home/emil/import/testfile1.pdf
emil@TITAN:~/programmering$ ls /home/emil/import/
'test file2.pdf'  'test file3.pdf'   testfile1.pdf
```

So where am I going wrong?